# Can subviews count as using undocumented APIs in iOS?

Tags: ios, api

Does using (for example) `UIWebView`'s subviews count as using undocumented APIs? There is no documentation on the fact that the first subview of a `UIWebView` is a `UIScrollView`. Does that mean that I am not allowed to add children to this `UISCrollView`?

I'm not using any private calls, but it isn't documented anywhere. In iOS 3.1 the first subview of a `UIWebView` is an instance of a class called `"UIScroller"`, which is almost identical to the `UIScrollView`, but not documented anywhere. What is allowed exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)

> For complex views declared in UIKit
>   and other system frameworks, any
>   subviews  of the view are generally
>   considered private and subject to
>   change at any time. Therefore, you
>   should not attempt to retrieve or
>   modify subviews for these types of
>   system-supplied views. If you do, your
>   code may break during a future system
>   update.

From [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html):

> Apps that do not use system provided
>   items, such as buttons and icons,
>   correctly and as described in the
>   Apple iOS Human Interface Guidelines
>   may be rejected

Taken together, I read these as saying: You can look at the subviews of standard components, but mess with them at your own peril -- things will change with no notice, and you'll have nobody to blame but yourself when they break. Furthermore, if you do modify a standard component in a way that's out of keeping with what Apple designed and users expect, your app will likely be rejected.

Modifying the private subviews of UIWebView seems like a poor plan.

Comment: This sums it up pretty well. While people *have* done so, it's bad practice because any iOS update can break your app.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it counts as using private APIs (correct me if I'm wrong), but I wouldn't recommend it. As you say: "in iOS 3.1" it works that way, but it's not guaranteed to work the same on other versions. It may change with an update and the application will break.

By the way, very few use iOS 3.1, so I would recommend looking at how it works in 4.3.

**EDIT:** I have never uploaded an app to app store where I've done this, but I can tell you this much: You do not submit any source code to Apple. They run your executable in a tool that will detect if you call any private API methods.

Looping through subviews is allowed. So is adding subviews. They don't even mention this in the [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html). I can't make any guarantees, since I'm not involved in Apple's review process, but I would be very surprised if they would reject your app for this reason.

If you feel like it would add value to your app I would go ahead and do it. If you submit your app to the app store and get it approved, please come back and leave a comment.

Comment: @ErikPerik Of course. Some recent stats: http://blog.jcmultimedia.com.au/2011/03/is-it-worth-supporting-ios-3-in-2011.html

Comment: Thanks! But it still doesn't answer the question of the sanctity of subviews.

Comment: @ErikPerik I've updated my answer to better answer your question. If you want a better answer I think it will have to be provided by someone that either works for Apple or have done this and gotten their app approved or rejected.